# datepicker/moment.js ? displaying wrong date in my locale

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, momentjs

im integrating twitter bootstrap datepicker plugin, but im having trouble with it.

The plugin in question is this: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It works fine with default configuration(uses 'en' language as default).
But when I try to use different localization for example 'lv' it shows wrong date. 
The day and month are flipped(shows that current time is july 6 not april 4 what is correct in my location). 
I checked other localizations and it seems to be wrong too, even in the plugins documentation page, the 'ru' localization example has the same problem.

Correct
[image]

Wrong
[image]

For localization this plugin uses moment.js, (it does support 'lv' localization) which I included.

Any idea what wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it by providing date format MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm.

Thanks for anyone who checked this out.